Retro Japanese anime movie where a boy reincarnates into the spirit world with a witch or demon princess
Trying to remember this anime that seemed from the 90s or earlier.
It had a boy who falls in love with a witch and goes to the spirit world with her and then gets caught up in all sorts of drama I can’t remember. By the end, they reincarnate as entirely new beings.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And did you watch it on TV?
